# Geographic address of person selected in person picker (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController), formatted

Tags: ios, addressbook, abaddressbook, abperson

Showing a person picker with `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`, I can get the address of the selected person in a dictionary with this:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
    if (property == kABPersonAddressProperty) {
        ABMultiValueRef addressMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);    

        NSDictionary *address = (NSDictionary *)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressMultiValue, ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(addressMultiValue, identifier)));

    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;
}
```

Depending on the country, the convention on how to format this address is not the same.
Is there a way to get the string of the address as displayed by the picker (similar to what Contacts.app shows)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to dynamically create a set of editable address fields as you see in Contacts.app, but there is a utility function in AddressBookUI that allows you to format an address dictionary into a region-specific address string: [`ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Functions/Reference/reference.html). This function relies on the country code value being set correctly; it's unspecified what happens if this value is missing.

Comment: Great, that is what I was looking for. I do not understand why this is in AddressBookUI, and probably why I did overlook it.